# iOS 5 Data Storage: Core Data, SQL or other options?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, ios5

I am working on an application for the iPhone (iOS 5). What I have to do is create a map by using binary data that I reveive from a server. Some issues actually work quite well:

- I can connect to a server, send requests and receive binary data from it
- I can interprete this data, create objects (polygons and paths) from it and draw them within a view

But now it comes to the hard part. The map that I create should be zoomable and moovable. So I have to send new requests to the server and redraw the map. This also works nicely, but the data I already received now needs to be stored, because I should not request the same data from the server twice (e.g. if I zoom out and then back in).

Finally here is my question: What would be the best way to store my data? Until now I thought about using CoreData or SQLite. Are there even better solutions? And what data should I save - the binary data or my created objects?

I hope this was understandable and you can help me with at least one of my issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core data is the only way to go. 
Core data is not a storage system, is an object graph and persistence framework, witch can use SQlite to store data.

If you use core data you can refactor your project and use managedObjects subclass as models.

Take a look at [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html), [The differences between Core Data and a Database](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html)

Edit:

From [Core Data Performance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW1)

> Core Data is a rich and sophisticated object graph management
>   framework capable of dealing with large volumes of data. The SQLite
>   store can scale to terabyte sized databases with billions of
>   rows/tables/columns. Unless your entities themselves have very large
>   attributes (although see “Large Data Objects (BLOBs)”) or large
>   numbers of properties, 10,000 objects is considered to be a fairly
>   small size for a data set.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answer. So you mean I should keep my objects and access them with CoreData. Am I getting you right? Will this still be the best option for a huge amount of data?

Comment: I have edited my post. If you have to save blobs you can save them to documents directory and save in the db only the path to it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Now I have a point to start from.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the size of your data objects and how you access them.  If your objects are small, you could store them in Core Data.  But, if your map data is coming as images from a bunch of URLs, I would use Core Data to store the mappings to the map image URLs and use NSURLConnection to manage the caching of your objects.

I recommend reading the [Apple Core Data Programming Guide Large Data Objects (BLOBs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW5), it discusses the size and number of objects.  Some excerpts are below:

> The exact definition of "small", "modest", and "large" is fluid and depends on an application's usage. A loose rule of thumb is that objects in the order of kilobytes in size are of a "modest" sized and those in the order of megabytes in size are "large" sized.
>
> For small to modest sized BLOBs (and CLOBs), you should create a separate entity for the data and create a to-one relationship in place of the attribute.
>
> It is better, however, if you are able to store BLOBs as resources on the filesystem, and to maintain links (such as URLs or paths) to those resources. You can then load a BLOB as and when necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't receive image data from the server, but objects containing points with a latitude and longitude. Also I get a render rule for each object so I know how to draw it. Could you please define what you consider to be a 'small' object

Comment: Updated the answer with object sizing info.